# why is my command prompt not entering my key?

Tags: c#, windows, command-prompt

I'm using Visual Studio and coding in C#, my roommate and I found ccrypt encryption software that runs in the windows command prompt. I told him to send me a file and not tell me the key and then I would write a program to find out the key. So I have this as my code

```
            try{
                using (Process p = new Process())
                {
                    // set start info
                    p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe")
                    {
                        RedirectStandardInput = true,
                        UseShellExecute = false,
                        WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Users\alecp\ccrypt"
                    };
                    // event handlers for output & error
                    p.OutputDataReceived += p_OutputDataReceived;
                    p.ErrorDataReceived += p_ErrorDataReceived;

                    // start process
                    p.Start();
                    // send command to its input
                    p.StandardInput.WriteLine("ccrypt -d tryme.txt"); //1
                    p.StandardInput.WriteLine("key"); //2
                    //wait
                    p.WaitForExit();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
```

In the command prompt, line 1 will input and run with no error, but when it does run, it prompts a second prompt for entering the key, so I ran another command to input the key (line 2). The problem is line 1 waits for input it seems like so line 2 doesn't run until I press "enter" and return a new line in command prompt. Could someone explain what's going on here? Or how I could get around that? I'm slightly confused and just would like some guidance. Thank you all for your time!

Comment: It works same as console application.  Each Writeline in the code is equivalent to a a person in a console typing a command and ending the command with a return.

Comment: _I told him to send me a file and not tell me the key and then I would write a program to find out the key_. It seems that you've overstated your abilities when talking to your roommate.